# How to install Lets-encrypt on a different server same domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, encryption, amazon-ec2

Im using aws ec2 instances. I had an instance with ssl installed using Lets-encrypt that instance has been destroyed. I started a new instance with the same domain pointed to it and when I try to install ssl using lets encrypt I get this error

```
   ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-rEhjk0/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('
', '
'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-AX0i_f-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/.local/share/letsencrypt/include/site/python2.7/cryptography" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rEhjk0/cryptography
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
You are using pip version 8.0.3, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have tried with no success

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install requests[security]
pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```